# Automatically create new PODS on Kubernetes with Jenkins when Jira bug is created

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jira

I just have this concept that i want to implement on our environment and i just want to ask if there is any way i can do it.

So, I want to configure `Jenkins` and `GKE` to automatically provision a pod with the current state of an application, and database, when creating a bug in `Jira`. Basically I want `Jenkins` to get triggered by an issue created by an user, in `Jira`, and then build a replica of the application when the issue got created.

My question is this: Can `GKE` be manipulated or linked in some way with `Jenkins` so that it'll create a snapshot of the `App + Database` and then create a new Pod based on those 2 snapshots?

The workflow should be something like this:
`Jira => Jenkins => GKE (snapshots) => GKE (Pods creating)`

I would like Jenkins to communicate with `GKE` and get on creating a new set of `Pods` automatically, so that i won't have to intervene in any way.

Is there any way i can do something like this? This is just a concept for now, I'm not rushing on anything, just asking for some opinions on this.

Any ideas or suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not specific to GKE. It's about Kubernetes. You probably need to write some code and use the Kubernetes API to achieve what you described, which is a pretty custom use case/workflow.

Some pointers on using the Kubernetes API: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do. For each new Jira task:

- Create a new branch in the code repository, from the "live" one.
- Take a backup of the database.
- Deploy a new instance of the application with this branch and database backup. You probably want to use a cluster or a namespace per Jira task.

To deploy Kubernetes resources from Jenkins you can use the [DevOps steps](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-pipeline-plugin/blob/master/devops-steps/readme.md) of the [Kubernetes Pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Pipeline+Plugin) plugin.

You can use [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) to run the database backup and restore tasks.